# Database constraint over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Weeks] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Weeks] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [Days] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [WeekId] INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Days] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Days_Weeks_WeekId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WeekId]) REFERENCES [Weeks] ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [ReplacedDayInWeek] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [WeekId] INT NOT NULL,
    [DayId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ReplacedDayId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ReplacedDayInWeek] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ReplacedDayInWeek_Days_DayId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([DayId]) REFERENCES [Days] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ReplacedDayInWeek_Weeks_WeekId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WeekId]) REFERENCES [Weeks] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ReplacedDayInWeek_Weeks_ReplacedWeekId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ReplacedWeekId]) REFERENCES [Weeks] ([Id])
);
```

The table ReplacedDayInWeek contains a day in a specific week that's replaced by another day.

How can I create a SQL constraint (or perhaps another SQL based solution) that makes sure I can only insert rows into `DayInWeek` with a `DayId` that's part of the same week as `WeekId`?

I'm looking for a solution with the least amount of changes to the source database. I'd prefer an additional table or table changes above stored procedures.

Comment: how about using [check constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) and possibly [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as well?

Comment: Looks like triggers might be the way to go here. Was looking for a structural change in the tables (maybe an additional table) that would enforce my constraint naturally. But if such a change is not possible, I'll probably create a constraint. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the question was too simplified. I've updated it to make it more clear why `DaysInWeek` (now `ReplacedDayInWeek`) exists.

Answer (score 2):

This data structure makes no sense to me.  You have the mapping between days and weeks in *two* tables.

You should really only be storing the week in one table and looking it up in the other.

That said, you can do what you want using an additional constraint on day/week between the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Days] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [WeekId] INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Days] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Days_Weeks_WeekId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WeekId]) REFERENCES [Weeks] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_Days_WeekId_Id UNIQUE (WeekId, Id)
);

CREATE TABLE [DaysInWeek] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [WeekId] INT NOT NULL,
    [DayId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DaysInWeek] PRIMARY KEY([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_DaysInWeek_Days_WeekId_DayId] 
        FOREIGN KEY (WeekId, DayId) REFERENCES Days(WeekId, Id),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_DaysInWeek_Weeks_WeekId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WeekId]) REFERENCES [Weeks] ([Id])
);
```

Comment: You're totally right that it doesn't make sense. As often is the case, it's a simplified case. But perhaps I've simplified it too much. I've updated the question to hopefully make it more logical. Please tell me if it makes more sense now (or if it still doesnt make any sense).